# issue when accessing oshi library in jsp

Tags: jsp, java-native-interface, oshi

I am getting the problem is grabbing details through JSP.
I am using following versions:
jna-4.2.2.jar,
slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar,
jna-platform-4.2.2.jar,
oshi-core-2.3.jar
The problem is whenever I execute my below code from JSP I get the errors stated below, but in normal Java App it works fine without any error?

Is this a bug with JSP? or Is there any other way to call it in JSP?

```
<%@page import="oshi.hardware.HardwareAbstractionLayer"%>
<%@page import="oshi.software.os.OperatingSystem"%>
<%@page import="oshi.SystemInfo"%>
<%
    SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
    OperatingSystem os = si.getOperatingSystem();
     HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
     out.println(hal.getProcessor());
%>
```

and the error is:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.IntegerType.<init>(IJZ)V
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$DWORD.<init>(WinDef.java:135)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$DWORD.<init>(WinDef.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.defaultValue(NativeMappedConverter.java:47)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.<init>(NativeMappedConverter.java:41)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.getInstance(NativeMappedConverter.java:29)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:717)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:251)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:153)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:143)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:139)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:130)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$MEMORYSTATUSEX.<init>(WinBase.java:595)
    at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsGlobalMemory.<init>(WindowsGlobalMemory.java:40)
    at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.getMemory(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.jsp.api.cpuload_jsp._jspService(cpuload_jsp.java:62)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please suggest some solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing two jar files

If you are using Netbeans:

> Goto Project Properties > Libraries > Compile > Add JAR

Now add two files:-

> javax.json-1.0.4.jar
>
> javax.json-api-1.0.jar

You can download them from here [json](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar) and [json-api](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/json/javax.json-api/1.0/javax.json-api-1.0.jar)

For documentation reference look here: https://jsonp.java.net/download.html

Comment: While using Apache Tomcat server the error does not occur but as soon as I switch to glassfish server 4.1 I get the error  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.IntegerType.<init>(IJZ)V`

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace line numbers indicate you're using jna-platform-4.2.2 but somehow your code is finding com.sun.jna.IntegerType somewhere else than jna-4.2.2.jar.

Try running this code:

```
Class klass = com.sun.jna.IntegerType.class;
URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

Then output location.toString() and verify it's in the jna-4.2.2 jar. You should get a result like

```
jar:file:/ ...path to jar... /jna-4.2.2.jar!/com/sun/jna/IntegerType.class
```

If not, you've found the location where Java's classloader is loading the incorrect class.   Then figure out how to exclude the class from that alternate location (remove the bad jar, use newer resource bundle, etc.)